# how to pass a database column as a parameter in a user defined function?

Tags: mysql, sql, user-defined-functions

i have a code in sql for string comparison which takes two parameters as input works upon it and returns a result. both of the parameters are words, i want to change the parameter from a single word to a database column. how do i do that?

say for example in java its like storing the data in an array and than passing the whole array. can something like this be done in sql?

Comment: thanks for the reply! mysql through wamp server

Comment: means you want to pass full column data as one string like column data  has "one" "two" "three' it pass as  "one,two,three"  not clear ??

Comment: if possible show user_defined function and then give example

Comment: hey mangesh, there is a column with city names and i want to compare my searched word with each of those names, means that starting from 0 till end....

Comment: function calling looks like this compare_city_name("baroda", "agra"), here my searched word is "baroda" but instead of passing "agra", i want to pass the values from that city name column one after the other.

Comment: then you can use query like SELECT compare_city_name('baroda',t.cityname) from tablename as t;

Comment: would have rather switched to chat option but as i am new here, i do not have that option yet.

Comment: @mangesh.. but this way i am referring to the whole column and the function is made to compare just 1 single word, which means i have to pass a single value instead of passing the whole column.

Comment: here one by one value of city name passed in function and in function it compare with baroda and return result for every row. check here  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/coRx4dFGLTRGwJJyXc3YLS/0

Comment: you can pass full citycolumn data as string to function using group_concat function output of group_concat is like "city1,city2,city3"

Comment: Which solution work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Select` query for passing each value of a particular column from the table into your function.
like this,

```
SELECT compare_city_name('baroda',t.cityname) from tablename as t
```

In this query, you pass all cities name from `cityname` column to the function `compare_city_name` one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Pass it as a `VARCHAR`, then build the query with "prepare" and "execute" it.